# Need help in multi-threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I am creating a crawler like app which will find images in the web pages. In here the producer produces the links and the consumer connects to that link for finding the images, but consumer was taking a lot of time because of huge number of links produced by the consumer. So I placed the consumer in the executor service but I could not find decrease in time taken by the consumer. Kindly help me out. Below is my code.

```
@Service
@Qualifier("crawlerService")
public class CrawlerService {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("loggerService")
LoggerService loggerService;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("imageTypeExtensionCombo")
ImageTypeExtensionCombo imageTypeExtensionCombo;

public List<String> startCrawler(List<String> links, List<String> images, URL url, String protocol, String protocolHost) throws Exception{
    LinkQueue queue = new LinkQueue(links);
    LinkProducer producer = new LinkProducer(links, url, protocol, protocolHost, queue, loggerService);
    LinkConsumer consumer = new LinkConsumer(links, images, url, protocol, protocolHost, loggerService, queue);
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    executorService.submit(consumer);
    producer.start();
    //consumer.start();
    Thread.currentThread().join();
    executorService.shutdown();
    return images;
  }
}
```

LinkProducer class

```
public class LinkProducer extends Thread {

    private List<String> anchorList;
    private URL url;
    private String protocol;
    private String protocolHost;
    private UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator();
    private LinkQueue queue;
    private LoggerService loggerService;
    private int MAX_QUEUE_SIZE = 2;
    private int counter = 0;
    private boolean stopThread = false;

    private String HTML_TYPE = "HTML";
    private String HTML_CONTENT_TYPE = "text/html";
    private String IMAGE_TYPE = "IMAGE";
    private String NON_HTML_NON_IMAGE_TYPE = "OTHERS";

    public LinkProducer(List<String> anchorList, URL url, String protocol,String protocolHost, LinkQueue queue, LoggerService loggerService) {

        super(protocolHost.replace(protocol, "").replaceAll("/", ""));
        this.anchorList = anchorList;
        this.url = url;
        this.protocol = protocol;
        this.protocolHost = protocolHost;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.loggerService = loggerService;

    }


    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        while(true) {
            List<String> anchors = null;
            loggerService.log("Producer Thread : " + (++i));
            try {
                anchors = produce();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                loggerService.log("Exception occured in producer thread : "+ ex.getMessage());
                ex.printStackTrace();
                if(stopThread){
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(stopThread){
                break;
            }
            if(anchors != null && anchors.size() > 0){
                Iterator<String> iter = anchors.iterator();
                while(iter.hasNext()){
                    synchronized (queue) {
                        queue.enQueue(iter.next());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

LinkConsumer class

```
public class LinkConsumer extends Thread {

    private List<String> anchorList;
    private List<String> imageList;
    private URL url;
    private String protocol;
    private String protocolHost;
    private LinkQueue queue;
    private LoggerService loggerService;
    private UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator();

    private String HTML_TYPE = "HTML";

    private String HTML_CONTENT_TYPE = "text/html";

    private String IMAGE_TYPE = "IMAGE";

    private String NON_HTML_NON_IMAGE_TYPE = "OTHERS";

    public LinkConsumer(List<String> anchorList, List<String> imageList, URL url, String protocol,String protocolHost, LoggerService loggerService, LinkQueue queue) {

        super(protocolHost.replace(protocol, "").replaceAll("/", ""));
        this.anchorList = anchorList;
        this.imageList = imageList;
        this.url = url;
        this.protocol = protocol;
        this.protocolHost = protocolHost;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.loggerService = loggerService;
    }

    public void run() {
        int  i = 0;
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            List<String> images = null;
            loggerService.log("Consumer Thread : " + (++i));
            try {
                images = consume();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                loggerService.log("Exception occured in consumer thread : "+ ex.getMessage());
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (images != null && images.size() > 0) {
                Iterator<String> iter = images.iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    imageList.add(iter.next());
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show us the `LinkProducer` and `LinkConsumer` classes.

Comment: You are doing IO.. Not sure if increasing the number of threads will do any good

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().join()` - you want the current thread to wait for the current thread to die? Hmm.

Comment: @AndyTurner I want the current thread to wait for the producer and consumer to complete.

Comment: How are you measuring the time? Note that parallel computation doesn't always mean faster.

Comment: In that case you'd probably need to use `producer.join()` and `consumer.join()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create and submit only a single `LinkConsumer` and therefore you have only one worker.

To achieve real parallel performance you will need to create and submit more `LinkConsumer`.

Answer (score 1):

Multi-threading doesn't give you much of an advantage. Infact, it increases the complexity, when you are creating too many threads and when your hardware isn't capable enough of processing these threads.

Multi-threading would give you significant gains, only if you use it efficiently. If you keep creating threads this way, you aren't going to gain any performance improvements.

Your hardware, especially processor specs and the volume of data you are writing to your disk are the primary constraints, which are going to decide the performance that you would get.

I would suggest the following. 
Have multiple machines. One machine, which acts as producer writes all URL's or images or what ever you want to a database. The client systems take the URL's from DB and fetch the data from the source.

Technically, you have multiple systems which are working and each machine could have ~10 active threads at a time. And you need to code only once and run the same code on multiple machines. You could use the same producer machine as consumer too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this to create new threads. But I'm not sure that creating new threads will increase time too much. You will need better Hardware as well.

```
  public boolean secondThread(){
    Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run(){


        //do somehting 

        }
    };
    t.start();
    return true;
}
```